# How to map JSON data with array in React component

Tags: node.js, arrays, json, reactjs

I have an array like this in React data file and I'm using the `.map()` method to load JSON data in component `ProjectItem.js`.

**question 1: solved** What is the most efficient way to find out if my code contains a value? '{data.title} isn't showing on my page at the moment. I've tried on applying some code as per document please have a look and help me.

***question 2:** What is the most efficient way to print nested JSON object? I now want to print the title in projects array so I can debug it. show on browser. I can't see  in inspector console.log(key) isn't showing on console (something is going wrong with the function).

**Data.json**

```
{
"projects": [
    {
        "title": "Projecttitle",
        "category": "frontend development",
        "description": "",
        "desktop": [],
        "mobile": []
    }
  ]
}
```

**ProjectItem.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './ProjectItem.scss';
import useWindowWidth from '../../Hooks/useWindowWidth.js';
import { projects } from '../../data'

import desktopImage from '../../Assets/Images/Projects/Desktop/123.jpg';
import mobileImage from '../../Assets/Images/Projects/Mobile/123_square.jpg'


const ProjectItem = ({ viewProject }) => {

const imageUrl = useWindowWidth() >= 650 ? desktopImage : mobileImage;

const { windowWidth } = useWindowWidth();
return(
    <div className="projectItem" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${ imageUrl })`}}>
        {windowWidth >= 650 &&( 
            <>
            <div className="title">
                {projects.map((data, key)=>{
                        console.log(key);
                    return(
                        <div key={key}>
                        {data.title}
                        </div>
                    );
                })} 
            </div>
            <div className="viewProject">{viewProject}</div>
            </>
        )}  
    </div>
    );
}; 

export default ProjectItem
```

**Console:**

empty

Comment: What value? Any value? `projects.length > 0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `length` property of the array to determine if the array is empty or not.

```js
const emptyArray = [];
const notEmptyArray = [1,2,3];

console.log(!emptyArray.length); // => true;
console.log(!notEmptyArray.length); // => false;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) for checking if an element is in an array.